# MySQL Connector Migration from 6.9.9 to 7.0.6

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, mysql-connector, isolation-level

We have migrated from MySQL .Net Connector 6.9.9 to .Net Connector 7.0.6 and we're using the connector for .NET version 4.5.1. Our ASP.NET project uses .NET 4.6.2 so we expect backward compatibility with this connector. The same code runs fine on the previous connector (6.9.9), however when using the new connector the following code throws an exception:
Message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=...; Pwd=..."))
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlTransaction tx = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
}
```

Why the new MySQL .Net connector (7.0.6) is throwing this exception whereas the previous connector (6.9.9) didn't? My version of Mysql is 5.6. It seems it's trying to execute a `DataReader` when opening the transaction.

The exception thrown is:

```
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.AddCallStatement(String query)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
```

Comment: Post the *full* exception, including the call stack. You can get it very easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Most likely you'll find that you passed a null somewhere

Comment: Also post code that actually reproduces the error. Otherwise this question should be closed as a duplicate of any other `NullReferenceException` question

Comment: BTW you didn't post the code that initializes `mConn`. You posted code that initializes and opens `connection`

Comment: Which shows that something goes wrong with the query. **PLEASE** post a complete code snippet! I'll bet that if you create a new console application with a simple query (no connection, query generators), you'll find that the provider isn't broken

Comment: I have expanded on the snippet, this works perfect with .Net connector 6.9.9 so I don't think the code itself is the issue

Comment: Write a *simple* snippet that reproduces the issue. Just a `using(var conn=new MySqlDbConneciton(){ conn.Open();  using(var tx=conn.BeginTransaction()){...}}`. These attempts to alias the ADO.NET classes simply confuse things - and make sure you can't know which connection you use.

Comment: BTW ADO.NET already provides abstractions through interfaces. By wrapping the methods you make them a *lot* harder to use. Besides, your methods will never return `false` - any problem results in an exception. What is the point?

Comment: `mDC` or `mIdentifier`? Why *store* the connection? Connection pooling means that ADO.NET takes care of reusing connections, you are just wasting resources this way, and you'll probably forget to close it at the end. Anyway, without a reproducible snippet, it's impossible to help. Create a clean console application, try with ADO.NET methods *only*, with a *single* connection. Remove all ambiguity. Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the problem with the added simple snippet, same exception when calling `BeginTransaction`

Comment: This issue reliably reproduces for me as well using 7.0.6 of the connector. The simplest repro is ... new MySqlConnection() ... .Open() ... .BeginTransaction().

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can confirm that the same code when using 6.9.9 worked and that I had the same stack trace as the OP.  I spent a bunch of time last night digging through the code and couldn't find it, unfortunately.